# Apache Camel retry delivery attempt log issue

Tags: spring-boot, logging, apache-camel, delay, retrypolicy

When retrying SQLException with max attempts of 3, i was logging the attempts and used below parameters for the same.

......
.maximumRedeliveries(3)
.redeliveryDelay(1000)
.asyncDelayedRedelivery()
.logRetryAttempted(true)
.log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "retry attempts exhausted")
.end();

The delivery attempts in the log are not in ascending order of the retry attempt made. Ex. "On delivery attempt: 3" was coming before "On delivery attempt: 2". Any thoughts on the issue please?

Camel Version : 3.4.0

I was expecting the delivery attempts in the log to be in ascending order of attempt made.

Comment: That could be because you have enable **asynchronous** redelivery (combined with a short delay). Try to remove  `asyncDelayedRedelivery()`and see if the order becomes ascending

Comment: Thank you @TacheDeChoco, but if i remove asyncDelayedRedelivery(), then the calling thread will go to sleep without serving any request